# R: How can I split a string into several strings depending on the string's elements' lengths

Tags: r, regex, stringr

My question consists of two parts:

1. How can I split a string into multiple strings based on its elements' lengths?
2. How can I dynamically create an a priori unknown number of strings based on the string's elements' lengths?

My goal is to split the string:

```
text <- "a.a 5bb c- dd e f"
```

into multiple strings depending on its elements' lengths:

```
string1 <- "e f"
string2 <- "c- dd"
string3 <- "a.a 5bb"
```

Furthermore, in my application, it is a priori unclear how many strings need to be created, because the string `text` might consist of elements of varying length depending on the context where the code is going to be executed.

Is it possible to dynamically create a flexible number of strings where the names of the strings to be created incorporate the length of the elements it collects? For instance, the string to be created that collects elements of length 9 should be named "string9".

Comment: Based on the lengths, the strings have different lengths

Comment: @akrun I assume that your comment refers to the second part of my question. The resulting strings that are to be created will most certainly be of different length, true. However, my question is not about the length of the string itself; my question is about the length of the elements that the string should collect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what criteria you are using to split your strings, but it is certainly possible to create a list of character vectors grouped and named by their length.

Suppose you have a string like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
x <- sample(c(" ", letters), 200, prob = c(0.3, rep(0.8/26, 26)), replace = TRUE)
x <- gsub(" +", " ", paste(x, collapse = ""))
x
#> [1] "kscwew t wey n tg co cn opxbhdqpiflaoic f jusfyn ssk m wfiwrhqyt 
zdjgspimramrunsqslo h dht pjnqgy vbo luy nrzkm gz m slu mgi wuqr qbreifaoz jg qe shga 
mfbuhe o dmwsor ko zmdpucv w a ugc"
```

And you want to split it into pieces according to where the spaces are, so you have a single long vector of multiple strings of various length (the "words" from the original string):

```
all_strings <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
```

Now all you need to do is `split` according to the length of the strings, which we get with `nchar`:

```
nchar_list <- split(all_strings, nchar(all_strings))
nchar_list
#> $`1`
#> [1] "t" "n" "f" "m" "h" "m" "o" "w" "a"
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] "tg" "co" "cn" "gz" "jg" "qe" "ko"
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] "wey" "ssk" "dht" "vbo" "luy" "slu" "mgi" "ugc"
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] "wuqr" "shga"
#> 
#> $`5`
#> [1] "nrzkm"
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] "kscwew" "jusfyn" "pjnqgy" "mfbuhe" "dmwsor"
#> 
#> $`7`
#> [1] "zmdpucv"
#> 
#> $`9`
#> [1] "wfiwrhqyt" "qbreifaoz"
#> 
#> $`15`
#> [1] "opxbhdqpiflaoic"
#> 
#> $`19`
#> [1] "zdjgspimramrunsqslo"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This looks about right! The only thing different from what I need is to have character vectors that consist of one string instead of many, that is, `"t n f m h ..."` instead of `"t" "n" "f" "m" "h" ...`. Playing around with `paste(..., collapse = ' ')` might solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Allan's reply, I could solve my problem. The following code achieves what I want.

```
library(dplyr)

text <- "a.a 5bb c- dd e f abcde 12345" 

string <- strsplit(text, " ")[[1]] %>% 
    split(., nchar(.)) %>% 
    lapply(., paste, collapse = ' ')
```